# Form hangs if an email is being typed when it pops

Tags: vba, forms, outlook

Outlook 2016 reminders are being missed whilst flashing in the tray, rather than taking focus, like they used to.

I pulled together some pieces of code that used to pop a simple, one button form, which took the system focus.

It worked for a while, however corporate updates caused it some issues. Although it's been tweaked it now has an annoying habit of displaying a partial form (title only, no button) which causes the Outlook process to go to 30% CPU and become unresponsive if I happen to be typing an email when the reminder pops.

Seems to be fine if other apps have focus.

This is what it looks like when it's broken:
[image: Hung form]

It should look like:
[image: Working form]

```
Option Explicit

Dim LastCalled      As Date


Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)

    If Now() > DateAdd("s", 30, LastCalled) Then
        LastCalled = Now()
        If TypeOf Item Is AppointmentItem Then
            MsgBox "Something's happening...", vbExclamation + vbSystemModal, "Check Reminders!"
            PopReminders.Show vbModal
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    LastCalled = DateValue("1/1/2017")
End Sub
```

The very simple form's details are:
[image: UserForm details]

How can I stop this hanging?

Comment: The issue occurs if/when an email is being typed when the form is triggered.

Comment: I have similar issue, outlook hangs when typing of user and showing up of the dialog occurs at the same time.

Comment: I got rid of the hanging by removing the vbModal from PopReminders.Show. There is some kind of race condition where it would prevent the standard Outlook reminders dialog from popping, if you happened to be typing an email when it was triggered. 

That's annoying, as I would like the pop-up to be modal, to ensure it's not missed. Not sure how to move forward from here...

Comment: I check it with Process Explorer, one of the thread of Outlook hangs with stack top at 'ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x5f46'. From the symbol name of the stack, it seems that there is indeed some kind of race condition. What I'm trying to do is show a mode-less window, and auto close it several seconds later. So, there is a loop with time check after the show of the forum. I remove vbModeless My experiment shows that the DoEvents in the loop would cause the hang. Without the DoEvents, my typing would hang for a little period, but it would go back to normal latter.